# LESS to CSS conversion

Tags: css, less

I'm very eager to start working with LESS. I've been trying to figure out how should I convert my LESS to CSS. I googled and found a lot of things which actually confused me more rather than making things simple.

1. I do not want to install ruby. And I do not want to install .net on my PC (found this 1 method from google.)
2. I read about 'SimpLESS' by some say it is outdated. (Their last blog post was in July 2012)
3. The easiest was I read about was to just use the Less.js file and all will be done. But then they say it is not good for production.

Can anyone please help me find a way out for this problem.

Comment: Have you read the ginormous list of all the ways you can convert LESS on the official website? http://lesscss.org/usage/

Comment: you can try this online tool. http://less2css.org/

Comment: @deceze Yes I read that. I had been and still trying to avoid node.js. Don't know why but mostly because of cmd line.

Comment: @Rishabh Shah I would suggest you to go for Node.js if not now you will use it in future for sure.

Comment: And forget about programs that you have to run, try to automate this, because sooner or later you will be fed up that you have to compile less every time you fix a small chunk in less.

Comment: @TheCodeDestroyer Sorry if this sounds lame but can you tell me how to automate this?

Comment: @Rishabh Shah Well depends when do you want to automate the compilation on some sort of Continous Integration which i then recommend TeamCity or Jenkins. Or fi you want to do it on the fly when a file changes then you have another node plugin which watches your files and executes a task when the file changes

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

Comment: @TheCodeDestroyer thank you very much. I'd look into these things. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with Grunt I would suggest that you try this:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-less

Here is a nice tutorial to get you started with grunt:

http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/A+Tutorial+for+Getting+Started+with+Grunt

Comment: Its 4 lines in cmd and you're done for life then just setup a build step that does that for you.

Comment: Ok that gives me a bit courage. Do I need to know node or grunt for using LESS of it is just for the compilation that I'd need grunt?

Comment: Just compilation it will take you tops an 1 hour to set everything up from scratch, then you can forget about it even write a batch file in your project root that runs grunt less compile command

Answer (score 2):

Try Crunch APP - http://crunchapp.net/
It is the most simplest LESS to css out there.

Comment: thnx.. crunch looks good but is there any way I can be sure that it is not outdated like `SimpLESS`?